# If I have a function $f(x,y)$ so that $Df(x,y)$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$, what can I say over $D(f\circ f)(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose I have a function $f(x,y)$ where $Df(x,y)$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$. Suppose also I have a function $g = f\circ f$. Is there anything I can say about $Dg(x,y)$?

Note, that $a,b$ may well be functions here.

Comment: Have you tried applying the chain rule?

Comment: Yeah, but that only tells me that $Dg(x,y) = \left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}\circ f\right)\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{bmatrix}$. It seems like you should be able to tell something more. I did make a small change in the post clarifying that $a,b$ may be functions, so just multiplying the matrices isn't something you can do, as $f$ works on one but may not do so on the other.

Comment: You can still multiply the matrices, but you have to evaluate the first one at $f(x,y)$. It may becomemore clear if you look at the components, e.g. $\partial_x f_x(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y))$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: Jacobi matrix for composition $f(g(x,y))$ is product of Jacobi matrices for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$